# How to convert datarow to string of array?

Tags: c#, arrays, datarow

I have a DataRow, I need convert it to a string of array!
Everyone help me, please!
Ex:
MyDataRow include many column(Index type of int, Name type of string, Age type of int.... )
`=> to array`
`array[0]: 1`
`array[1]: Henry`
`array[2]: 23`
`....`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as a start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DataRow itself has property ItemArray, you can use it.
Try this code

```
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    object[] arr = dr.ItemArray;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
         sb.Append(Convert.ToString(arr[i]));
         sb.Append("|");
    }
 }
Response.Write(sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

simply you can convert as follows.

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
var rows = dt.AsEnumerable().ToArray();
int num = 0;
string[] strarr = new string[rows.Length];
foreach (DataRow raw in rows)
{
    strarr[num] = raw.ItemArray[0].ToString(); 
    num++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy with Linq:

```
dr.ItemArray.Select(c => c.ToString()).ToArray();
```